# Reference an object when Instantiated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some time now I've been trying to reference a GameObject. This game object carries a "route" for my instantiated object to travel on. All that needs to take place is for the Game object to be referenced by the instantiated object.
[Transform is where the Gameobject will Go.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0nkK.png)

How, in this special case, since the number of "routes" could be a variable, referencing the gameobject has been difficult as it's not a single variable slot, but rather a setting for more variables (if wanted). [As you can see there are multiple Routes, and they contain the positions for the Route, but I will only be using one object currently.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KULnt.png)

So is there a way to change the number of elements to 1 (element0) by default, maybe making it a singular variable, and then also reference the Routes game object in the scene?

Below is my code that would be in the instantiated preFab. I believe GameObject.Find will be along those lines:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Streaker2Route : MonoBehaviour

{
    [SerializeField]
private Transform[] routes;

private int routeToGo;

private float tParam;

private Vector2 objectPosition;

public float speedModifier = 0.3f;

private bool coroutineAllowed;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    routeToGo = 0;
    tParam = 0f;
    coroutineAllowed = true;
    speedModifier = 0.3f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (coroutineAllowed)
    {
        StartCoroutine(GoByTheRoute(routeToGo));
    }
}

private IEnumerator GoByTheRoute(int routeNum)
{
    coroutineAllowed = false;

    Vector2 p0 = routes[routeNum].GetChild(0).position;
    Vector2 p1 = routes[routeNum].GetChild(1).position;
    Vector2 p2 = routes[routeNum].GetChild(2).position;
    Vector2 p3 = routes[routeNum].GetChild(3).position;

    while (tParam < 1)
    {
        tParam += Time.deltaTime * speedModifier;

        objectPosition = Mathf.Pow(1 - tParam, 3) * p0 + 3 * Mathf.Pow(1 - tParam, 2) * tParam * p1 + 3 * (1 - tParam) * Mathf.Pow(tParam, 2) * p2 + Mathf.Pow(tParam, 3) * p3;

        transform.position = objectPosition;
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    tParam = 0f;

    routeToGo += 1;

    if (routeToGo > routes.Length - 1)
    {
        routeToGo = 0;
    }

    coroutineAllowed = true;

}
```

}

Comment: are you asking how to turn it from an array to just a single Transform? I don't quite understand what the question is here.

Comment: Yes, someone assisted me on this school project. That would be great, thank you.

Comment: *Yes, someone assisted me on this school project* - that's the pickle you get yourself in when you ask someone to do your work for you; if you can't understand the result then you cannot easily explain to the next person who you ask for help with your work, how the existing work works.. Always make sure you fully understand the code you curate, and ask to be taught rather than given the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead:

```
 Vector2 p0 = routes[routeNum].GetChild(0).position;


 objectPosition = Mathf.Pow(1 - tParam, 3) * p0;
```

So delete the other stuff and instead of using 4 positions just use 1. In this case p0.

The downside is you will have to make a whole new script with these changes and then decide before hand if you want to use 1 position(new script) per route or 4(your old script).

If you want the script to detect how many positions it needs to use per route then you need to ask the question differently and hope someone has a script laying around or is willing to spend their time to write you a robust one, which could take hours depending on who you ask.